Why does std::vector constructor throw std::length_error instead of std::bad_alloc?
Consider the following example:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <new>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>::size_type n;
    std::cout << "Enter array size: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    try
    {
        std::vector<int> v(n);
        std::cout << "Allocation worked!\n";
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Allocation failed: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}

If I use input 10'000'000'000 it throws std::bad_alloc, as it should:
Enter array size: 10000000000
Allocation failed: std::bad_alloc

But if I use 18'446'744'073'709'551'615 (which is the maximum 64-bit value), it throws std::length_error, which is not a bad_alloc and thus crashes:
Enter array size: 18446744073709551615
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  cannot create std::vector larger than max_size()

I do understand that std::vector has a max_size() member which is supposed to tell me the maximum number of elements the container can hold due to implementation limits (rather than runtime memory limits). But it's not specified anywhere that if I exceed this size, it should throw std::length_error instead of std::bad_alloc. The only std::vector member which should do this is reserve, but I am not calling it.
I expected the code to throw std::bad_array_new_length, because std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof(T) < n. This would work well here, because std::bad_array_new_length is derived from std::bad_alloc and thus it would be caught.
How should I correctly handle the allocation error? One easy way out is to just catch std::exception, but this means that I can't filter other exceptions if I want to. On the other hand, I don't know when I should be prepared for a std::length_error, since it's not mentioned anywhere. Does the standard specify exactly which exceptions are allowed to be thrown by a certain function? Can I see this list anywhere?

std::length_error is thrown by, for example, std::vector<T>::reserve. It might be that your implementation of std::vector uses reserve to allocate memory.

Why not catch both?

@DarkAtom Perhaps you should clarify that you wonder why it's throwing length_error rather than bad_array_new_length?

I recommend you catch the exception in a debugger, to see when and where it's thrown and under what conditions.

@NathanOliver because I cannot know when I should catch it. It's not documented anywhere.

@TedLyngmo bad_array_new_length is derived from bad_alloc, so my program should catch it.

@DarkAtom I know that. Isn't your question why it's not throwing bad_array_new_length as specified by std::allocator but instead throws length_error?

Yes, I will edit my question and word it this way.

@DarkAtom Where you would do one you should do the other.  How do you know when to check for bad_alloc?  Same place might throw a length_error as well.

@NathanOliver I know when to check for bad_alloc because it is specified in the standard. std::vector constructor throws if Allocator::allocate throws. "Same place might throw a length_error as well." Source? Searching in the C++17 draft PDF for length_error only yields results in std::vector<T>::reserve (which I'm not using) and in std::basic_string (which I'm not using).

@DarkAtom If you are looking for the exact place where the C++ standard specifies something, you should add the [tag:language-lawyer] tag.

*I expected the code to throw std::bad_array_new_length - why? The call to the constructor does not reach the call to the allocator.

Any time the capacity grows you have to consider reserve being used to do that growing.   Those are implementation details though and not something the standard is going to mandate.

@DarkAtom "One easy way out is to just catch std::exception, but this means that I can't filter other exceptions if I want to" - yes, you can. You can have multiple catch's on a single try for different types. You can also dynamic_cast the std::exception to test it for specific derived types.

You already got the answer
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  cannot create std::vector larger than max_size()

The exception is thrown because 18'446'744'073'709'551'615 is greater than std::vector<T>::max_size().
This is an implementation specific limitation. The distance between two pointers (begin() i.e. &front() and end() i.e. after &back()) can't be 18'446'744'073'709'551'615, otherwise begin() and end() after overflow would point the same location.
Also take sizeof(T) into account. It's obvious that 18'446'744'073'709'551'615 * sizeof(T) can't fit into the 64-bit memory.
Also take into account that actual x86_64 CPUs can address only with 48 meaningful bits.
vector#capacity-5

Throws: length_error if n > max_size().

length.error#1

The class length_error defines the type of objects thrown as exceptions to report an attempt to produce an object whose length exceeds its maximum allowable size.

container.reqmts#57

c.max_size() Returns: distance(begin(), end()) for the largest possible container.


Maybe I worded my question wrong. I get why this happens. My question is where in the standard is it specified? I don't see this behavior being documented anywhere.

If you look at the std::vector constructor, you can see that it says "Calls to Allocator::allocate may throw.". Since it's the default allocator, this function (std::allocator::allocate) can only throw std::bad_alloc (or std::bad_array_new_length).

I see you've edited your post. What does the architecture have to do with this question? The fact that the CPU only has 2^47 bytes of virtual memory available (not 2^48, because half of it is taken by the OS) has nothing to do with my question. By the way, my max_size() is 0x1fffffffffffffff, which is way beyond what the CPU can address.

@DarkAtom If you try to allocate max_size() you'll likely get a bad_alloc. If you try max_size() + 1 you'll get a length_error - it will not even try to allocate more than max_size() but will  throw directly instead.

0x1fffffffffffffff is implementation detail. The question "why" can be answered only to a specific C++ standard library and version. The standard says Throws: length_error if n > max_size(). It does not specify max_size() value.

@273K The standard only says that for the reserve() member function, which I am not using in my code.

@DarkAtom The standard says "The class length_error defines the type of objects thrown as exceptions to report an attempt to produce an object whose length exceeds its maximum allowable size." - This exception is thrown by many containers and their constructors and member functions.

How do you imagine constructing a vector w/o changing its capacity with reserve()?

@TedLyngmo So are you saying that the standard doesn't specify exactly what exceptions each and every function is allowed to throw?

@DarkAtom As a rule, it doesn't have to. A lot of the specifications are narrow contracts. But in this case it does define that std::length_error is thrown in this case via its definition of what std::length_error is. The standard is not meant to be reader friendly, consequently all the information about a function isn't required to be localized together. You unfortunately need to consider the whole standard at all times when trying to understand what it says about any topic.

@DarkAtom No, I can't see that, but you noticed that it said so for reserve(), so which standard are you reading? I'm looking at the C++23 draft. Edit: You are reading the C++17 standard I guess. On what page or in what chapter did you find the note on reserve() on?

@DarkAtom As I understand, the C++ standard never mandates/guarantees that a function will not throw any exceptions not specifically listed, unless it is marked noexcept.

@heapunderrun So does that mean that a particularly hostile but conforming implementation is allowed to throw, let's say, bad_cast in the constructor, on the grounds that its bogus allocator needs to use dynamic_cast somewhere?

@TedLyngmo reserve() is described in 26.3.11.3 in N4659.

@DarkAtom Yeah I found it.  I'm trying to find a more general clause for when length_error is thrown, but it's possible that it's only in the length_error description we get that. The standard isn't easy reading :-)

@TedLyngmo the problem isn't that it's difficult to read, but that the definition itself is very loose. Does it mean, for example, that if I try to new int[n] it should throw length_error? It throws bad_array_new_length. EDIT: It seems that the standard clearly defines that bad_array_new_length is defined only for allocations of arrays (so I guess not std::vector). But then when would std::allocator throw it? Isn't std::vector internally making an array?

@DarkAtom Not sure about extreme cases or exotic implementations, but one classical example is the std::vector::operator[], which is not marked noexcept by the standard, probably for the very reason to allow implementations to do bounds checking if desired. And at least some implementations do throw in std::vector::operator[] in debug builds (but typically not in release builds).

@heapunderrun That doesn't seem like a strong argument. Indexing outside bounds with operator[] is undefined behavior already. An implementation is perfectly allowed to violate the noexcept contract and throw anyway - it's already UB, it can do anything.

@DarkAtom Yes, the std::vector makes an array allocation via the allocator and std::allocator would throw bad_array_new_length if it got the chance. In case the limit is exceeded, it doesn't even get the chance to throw, since vector throws length_error after checking that the length doesn't exceed the limit  which happens before calling the allocator's allocate function.

Even if an internally used function (like reserve) throws, another member function or constructor could catch and rethrow. So the argument that reserve has to be used, is not fully convincing.


Throws: allocate may throw an appropriate exception.

Allocators have a max size as well, and throwing length error when you ask for above max size is an appropriate exception.
